# Cannot call value of non-function type 'String?'

Tags: swift, date-formatting

I am new to iOS development. I am trying to convert a date value which is in string format(2024-09-22) to 22 Sep 2024.

But I am getting:

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'String?'

while doing date formatting.

I am getting this error in `dateFormatter.dateFormat(from : dateString)`.

I have tried a below code for the formatting.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
let convertedDate = dateFormatter.dateFormat(from : dateString)
```

Could someone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: You first need to get Date from given String ("2024-09-22" format: "yyyy-MM-dd"). And create one more DateFormatter to convert Date to new String

Comment: @AndrewBogaevskyi I already have the value in dateString variable. If possible could you please provide me a code example?

Comment: The method `dateFormat(from:)` does not exist in `DateFormatter`. The issue with it probably related to custom implementation.

Comment: @AndrewBogaevskyi Thank you for mentioning the exact issue. I have tried your code and it is working fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to get `Date` from given `String` ("2024-09-22" format: "yyyy-MM-dd"). And create one more DateFormatter to convert `Date` to new `String`:

```
let dateString = "2024-09-22"

let dateFormatterToDate = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterToDate.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let date = dateFormatterToDate.date(from: dateString)

let dateFormatterFromDate = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterFromDate.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
let result = dateFormatterFromDate.string(from: date!) // 22 Sep 2024
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert the date string to another date string you have to convert it to `Date` and back to `String`, so you need an input and output format. An API `dateFormat(from` doesn't exist.

The default time zone is the current time zone and to get always English month names regardless of the current locale set the locale to `en_US_POSIX`

```
let dateString = "2024-09-22"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
    let convertedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```